# TCPDF MYSQL data retrieval and print in html table

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

i use tcpdf to generate pdf in my site...

i use the code to retrieve data from mysql and display it in a table in the pdf file...

```
$pdf->writeHTML('<table width="600px" border="1px">');

    //data iteration
        include('../connect.php');
         $rer = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaint WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') between '$rep_from' and '$rep_to' order by id DESC;",$con);

    while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($rer))
    {

    $id=$rr['id'];
    $c_id=$rr['ref_id'];
    $pdf->writeHTML('<tr><td>'.$c_id.'</td></tr>');
    }

    $pdf->writeHTML('<table>');
```

The problem  is the code and iteration works fine... but when i use table tags, i shows

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in tcpdf.php on line 22165
```

This line in the file has some thing to do with tables... what is wrong with my code???

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't see any call of `array_push()` but I would simply use `$your_array[] = 'some value';` instead.

Comment: Show tcpdf.php line 22165 where you use `array_push()`, and where you declare the array you use in `array_push()`

Comment: Did you note [this note](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ac3fdf25fcd36f1dce04f92187c621407) about writeHTML: **NOTE:** *all the HTML attributes must be enclosed in double-quote.*

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: The documentation states further: *IMPORTANT: The HTML must be well formatted* and [all examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.phps) show complete elements, not fragments, so I assume you've got to build your complete table in a string and give this string to $pdf->writeHTML().

Comment: the problem is i print the rows in iteration... so can't write a complete table code for WriteHTML()

Comment: I use prepared statement, this is a test code... But why is the logic not working???

Comment: You've got to concatenate your HTML table in just one single string. That's the way this class works. I've ever managed to concatenate such strings myself if needed. Instead of outputting it you add it to your string.

Comment: So is this a bug of TCPDF... Not the logic... Thanks VMai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation states that the HTML should be well formatted, I understand this that it should be well formed, complete elements from the opening tag until the closing tag. My experiments showed similar errors, if I didn't do that.

So you could rewrite this sample code to:

```
$html = '<table width="600px" border="1px">';

//data iteration
include('../connect.php');
$rer = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaint WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') between '$rep_from' and '$rep_to' order by id DESC;",$con);

while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($rer))
{
    $id=$rr['id'];
    $c_id=$rr['ref_id'];
    // concatenate a string, instead of calling $pdf->writeHTML()
    $html .= '<tr><td>'.$c_id.'</td></tr>';
}

$html .= '</table>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html);
```

You should see how the complete output gets collected in a string variable. Only the well formed complete table is given to `$pdf->writeHTML()`. That should work for you too.

*Note:*

This code should never see production. Use PDO or mysqli with parameterized prepared statements instead as tadman said in his comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response i had got the solution using concat... :)